# How to find a web-element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Unable to find an element on the webpage https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Need to find the 'Number of GPUs' web element on the above wedpage, click it and select '1' from the popping up dropdown.

I tried this Xpath:

```
//*[@placeholder='Number of GPUs']
```

but the webDriver does not see it:

```
ElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/*[@placeholder='Number of GPUs']"}
```

Precondition:

1. Machine type: n1-standard-8 (vCPUs: 8, RAM: 30GB)
2. 'Add GPUs' checkboxed checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate and click the element associated with the label as **Number of GPUs** as the desired element is [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[text()='Number of GPUs']//following::md-select-value[@class='md-select-value' and starts-with(@id, 'select_value_label')][1]/span/div[@class='md-text ng-binding']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to use the CSS selector below

```
md-select[placeholder='Number of GPUs']
```

You will likely need to add a wait before since clicking the Add GPUs checkbox exposes that dropdown.